# I cannot bit import with --compiler option

Tags: reactjs, typescript, bit.dev

I’m having a problem.
I want to import typescript compiler.
then I tried this command: `bit import bit.envs/compilers/typescript --compiler`

But it doesn’t worked. This is the error message:

```
bit import [ids...]

import components into your current workspace.
  https://docs.bit.dev/docs/sourcing-components
  you can use a pattern for multiple ids, such as bit import "utils/*". (wrap the pattern with quotes to avoid collision with shell commands)

Options
  -p, --path                  import components into a specific directory  [string]
  -o, --objects               import components objects only, don't write the components to the file system. This is a default behavior for import with no id  [boolean]
  -d, --display-dependencies  display the imported dependencies  [boolean]
  -O, --override              override local changes  [boolean]
  -v, --verbose               showing verbose output for inspection  [boolean]
  -j, --json                  return the output as JSON  [boolean]
      --conf                  write the configuration file (component.json) of the component (harmony components only)  [boolean]
      --skip-npm-install      do not install packages of the imported components. (it automatically enables save-dependencies-as-components flag)  [boolean]
  -m, --merge                 merge local changes with the imported version. strategy should be "theirs", "ours" or "manual"  [string]
      --dependencies          EXPERIMENTAL. import all dependencies and write them to the workspace  [boolean]
      --dependents            EXPERIMENTAL. import component dependents to allow auto-tag updating them upon tag  [boolean]
      --skip-lane             EXPERIMENTAL. when checked out to a lane, do not import the component into the lane, save it on main  [boolean]
      --all-history           relevant for fetching all components objects. avoid optimizations, fetch all history versions, always  [boolean]

Global
  -h, --help           show help
      --token <token>  authentication token
      --log            print log messages to the screen, options are: [trace, debug, info, warn, error, fatal], the default is info
      --safe-mode      bootstrap the bare-minimum with only the CLI aspect. useful mainly for low-level commands when bit refuses to load

Unknown argument: compiler
```

Maybe compiler option doesn’t into bit import…
This is my version info:

```
current (used) bvm version: 0.0.30
latest available bvm version: 0.0.30

current (used) bit version: 0.0.555
latest installed bit version: 0.0.555
latest available bit version: 0.0.555
```

Please help me…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `compiler` flag was removed in 0.0.537

the best place to get bit.dev answers is their community Slack here: https://join.slack.com/t/bit-dev-community/shared_invite/zt-o2tim18y-UzwOCFdTafmFKEqm2tXE4w.

Answer (score 0):

"compiler" is a legacy solution - Bit now has the more comprehensive "environment" property. Learn more here - https://harmony-docs.bit.dev/aspects/envs/